# javascript array return undefined

Tags: javascript

When I loop over an array, i put the whole array to console and it shows the items, thought when looping over it it returns undefined... how?!?

```
 console.log("CONNECTORS....");
var connectors = userItem.connectors;
                if (connectors.length > 0)
                    console.log(userItem.connectors);

                for (connectorIndex = 0, sublen = connectors.length; connectorIndex < sublen; connectorIndex += 1) {                        
                    console.log("CONNECTORS INDEX " + connectorIndex);
                    console.log(connectors[connectorIndex]);
```

[image]

Comment: A JSFiddle with some context for your code would be helpful.

Comment: Works for me -> http://jsfiddle.net/mo25ew68/

Comment: Is there some ambiguity between `userItem.connectors` vs `connectors`?

Comment: In my code it's returning undefined... though it is actually fetching the first one.... and displaying the items... I'm so confused

Comment: no, they are the same...

Comment: i added the declaration which was missing in the code i posted, but was already in my code

Comment: Can you post the rest of your code?

Comment: There's a missing closing "}", but that's likely just a typo…

Comment: I've got it... explicitly moving it to a different value and then iterate over it made it work... somehow it must have been "changed" during the iterations. thanks for the help...